# Magento different cms home for themes

Tags: magento

we use a custom template and try to add rwd template for mobile use.
We add an exception for the mobile devices but need now to use an different "home" cms for the rwd template.

Where can I define the cms which is used for the homepage?

I have tried to change the cms.xml

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="core/template" name="default_home_page" template="cms/default/homeown.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

and created the cms page homeown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please add your code under `<cms_index_index>` tag

```
 <cms_index_index>
       <reference name="content">
         <block type="core/template" name="default_home_page" template="cms/default/homeown.phtml"/>
       </reference>
    </cms_index_index>
```

Comment: you can add this to local.xml as well as in cms.xml (in rwd theme)